# Fancybox iframe not working in IE11 with the hash url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, fancybox

I have implemented Fancybox code in AngularJS and angularjs using "#" for creating their URLs. Fancybox working properly in all browser except IE11. Please see my code:

```
$(document).on('click','.iframePopup',function(){
    var id_role = $(this).data('roleid');
    $.fancybox.open([
        {
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600,
        'speedOut'      :   200,
        type            :   'iframe',
        href            :   basePath + '#/getuser-list/'+id_role, 
        title           :   false,
        iframe          :   {
            preload     :   false
        }
        }
    ]);
});
```

Please suggest me any proper solution for that, so this fancybox open properly in IE11 as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What version are you using? Have you tried the latest (currently v3.1) ?

Comment: Not Working means fancybox open but no contented loaded. I am using version: 2.1.5.

Comment: Check developer tools for any JS error message that would help to identify the cause of the issue. Also, consider upgrading to v3.

Comment: No error in console, I get a spinning circle with no PDF. Works great in Chrome